# Cannot resolve symbol repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a StudentRepository and a Student Config file but when I try to had a `repository.saveAll` function in the StudentConfig file, I get an error saying `Cannot resolve symbol 'repository'` . Am I missing an obvious annotation somewhere?

I'm following this tutorial which is good but it misses a few things which is annoying https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SGDpanrc8U

## My Student repository file is like so:

package com.example.demo.student;

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

## My StudentConfig file is like so which contains the following error causer towards the bottom of the code block

```
repository.saveAll(
                        List.of(mariam, alex)
                )
```

: ->

```
package com.example.demo.student;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.List;


@Configuration
public class Studentconfig {

    // we want this bean
    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return args -> {
            Student mariam = new Student(
                    "Mariam",
                    "mariam.jamal@gmail.com",
                    LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 5)
            );

            Student alex = new Student(
                    "Alex",
                    "alex@gmail.com",
                    LocalDate.of(2004, Month.JANUARY, 5)
            );

            // invoke repository where we have the ability to save 1 student or list of all

            repository.saveAll(
                    List.of(mariam, alex)
            );
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a variable with the name `repository` defined anywhere. Perhaps you wanted to autowire it?

Comment: @voidvoid correct, when I hover over the repository, I get a suggestion to create a local repository. Where would I place the ```@Autowired``` annotation though? I've tried placing it in the Repository and Controller file but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems you are trying to do this:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationRunner implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository repository;
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Student mariam = new Student(
                        "Mariam",
                        "mariam.jamal@gmail.com",
                        LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 5)
                );
        
        Student alex = new Student(
                "Alex",
                "alex@gmail.com",
                LocalDate.of(2004, Month.JANUARY, 5)
        );
        
        repository.saveAll(
                List.of(mariam, alex)
        );
    }
}
```

Now your `StudentRepository` will get injected/autowired into your component and it will be available inside the run method.

Comment: that makes sense, however I had to delete ```public``` from ```public class ApplicationRunner``` because I was getting an error saying ```Class is public, should be declared in a file named .java```... according to other SO answers, you can only have 1 public in a file... does this make sense? or would be it better to delete the ```public``` in the ```public void run(String... args) throws Exception``` ?

Comment: Don't remove public, just put the class in a file named ApplicationRunner.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the ```@Override``` when I put the code in a ApplicationRunner.java file.. but when I put it into the ```StudentCongig.java``` file, it worked now without the ```Class is public, should be declared in a file named .java``` error because I mistyped the file name as ```Studentconfig.java``` instead of ```StudentConfig.java```. The students Mariam and Alex were successfully stored in my Postgres database and I can view them with a select * statement =D

Comment: not sure if I just did a hack way of doing it by putting it in the StudentConfig and it working but thanks!